# Finding the area and volume of flat washer, I am confused if my C program is correct. Need some validations

Tags: c

I am asked to calculate the volume and surface area of a flat washer where the outer diameter (d1) and the inner diameter (d2) and height (h) are provided by the user as input. I have solved the program but skeptical if my formulas are correct or not.

[For referance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKVXY.png)

Here is my solved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define pi 3.1416

int main()
{
    //declaration
    float D1,D2,r1,r2,volume,surface_area,h; 
    //taking input diameters and hight
    printf("Enter outer Diameter of the flat washer :");
    scanf("%f", &D1); 
    printf("Enter inner Diameter of the flat washer :");
    scanf("%f", &D2);
    printf("Enter height of the flat washer: "); 
    scanf("%f", &h); 
    //calculating radius
    r1=D1/2; 
    r2=D2/2; 
    //calculating volume
    volume=pi*((r1*r1)-(r2*r2))*h; 
    printf("Volume is %.4f\n",volume); 
    //calculating surface area
    surface_area=(2*pi*r1*(r1+h))-(2*pi*r2*(r2+h));
    printf("Surface area is %.4f",surface_area); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Are the numbers you are getting not as expected? Take a pen and a paper. A calculator perhaps. Calculate few examples using it. Then do the same with your program and compare.

Comment: I suggest you put all the math functions in separate functions, like `float circle_area(float r) { return pi * r * r; }` - it makes testing them separately and then combining them to get the results you want easier. It makes it easier to read and verify that you've done it correctly too.

Comment: Is it a math question about the formula to compute the volume and surface of a flat washer? Or something else?

Comment: I am getting expected numbers but I am unsure about the formulas I used in the code. @EugeneSh.

Comment: If you get the expected numbers, your code is correct, isn't it? And by the way, this website is about coding, not math.

Comment: Uncertain about the math formula part @fpiette

Comment: If you have tried *different* numbers as input and got the expected results, the code is probably correct. You can try corner cases, such as giving very big numbers, fractionals or zeros or negative numbers to see how these are handled.

Comment: Math formula ? Then ask in [this StackExchange math forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or just understand you have two cylinders to compute the volume and area of and then subtract the little one from the big one (for volume), the same for area, but you must account for the area of the inner diameter in that case.

Comment: Testing and verification is a task for you.  Please do not misuse SO as a free test house and/or lookup service for math formulae:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your math is correct for volume.

h * (πr<sub>outer</sub><sup>2</sup> - pir<sub>inner</sub><sup>2</sup>)

with a little factoring produces the formula you have.

Your math is wrong for surface area though. The natural form of the formula of the surface of a washer is

h * 2πr<sub>outer</sub> + 2(πr<sub>outer</sub>2 - πr<sub>inner</sub>2) + h * 2πr<sub>inner</sub>

which clearly doesn't match the forumula you have. You want:

`surface_area=h*2*pi*(r1+r2)+2*pi*(r1*r1-r2*r2);`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure but it may help: The formula for the surface could be wrong. Maybe you could try this:

Outer cylinder surface + inner cylinder surface + 2 x cylinder top surface

```
A = 2*pi*r1*h + 2*pi*r2*h + 2*pi*(r1^2 - r2^2)
A = 2*pi * [(r1 + r2) * h + (r1^2 - r2^2)]
```

Edit: Translating generic formula to c code in respect to Martin's comment. Please note that I'm using M_PI from math.h here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void)
{
    // ... all the input stuff and volume

    //calculating surface area
    surface_area = 2 * M_PI * ( (r1+r2)*h + r1*r1 - r2*r2 );
    printf("Surface area is %.4f",surface_area); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ^ is not an exponentation operator in C.